# How to increment element of block after found element?

Tags: red

Given `player-choices: ["rock" 0 "paper" 0 "scissors" 0]`

How could I increment the value after `"paper"` in this block by searching for `"paper"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>> player-choices/("paper"): player-choices/("paper") + 1
== 1
```

Comment: What do the parentheses do in this case?

Comment: Normally they evaluate what's inside, similar to a do. Here they  make it possible.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, also, that you may not need to use strings in your data block.

```
player-choices: [rock 0 paper 0 scissors 0]
player-choices/paper: player-choices/paper + 1
```

You can also write a generic `incr` func, like this:

```
incr: function [
    "Increments a value or series index"
    value [scalar! series! any-word! any-path!] "If value is a word, it will refer to the incremented value"
    /by "Change by this amount"
        amount [scalar!]
][
    amount: any [amount 1]

    if integer? value [return add value amount]         ;-- This speeds up our most common case by 4.5x
                                                        ;   though we are still 5x slower than just adding 
                                                        ;   1 to an int directly and doing nothing else.

    ; All this just to be smart about incrementing percents.
    ; The question is whether we want to do this, so the default 'incr
    ; call seems arguably nicer. But if we don't do this it is at 
    ; least easy to explain.
    if all [
        integer? amount
        1 = absolute amount
        any [percent? value  percent? attempt [get value]]
    ][amount: to percent! (1% * sign? amount)]          ;-- % * int == float, so we cast.

    case [
        scalar? value [add value amount]
        any [
            any-word? value
            any-path? value                             ;!! Check any-path before series.
        ][
            op: either series? get value [:skip][:add]
            set value op get value amount
            :value                                      ;-- Return the word for chaining calls.
        ]
        series? value [skip value amount]               ;!! Check series after any-path.
    ]
]
```

And then do

```
incr 'player-choices/paper
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also keep a reference to the positions of the values in the block to change them later:

```
player-choices: ["rock" 0 "paper" 0 "scissors" 0]
rock-pos: find/tail player-choices "rock"
paper-pos: find/tail player-choices "paper"
scissors-pos: find/tail player-choices "scissors"

change paper-pos 1 + paper-pos/1
player-choices
; == ["rock" 0 "paper" 1 "scissors" 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Given player-choices: ["rock" 0 "paper" 0 "scissors" 0] 
>   How could I increment the value after "paper" in this block by searching for "paper"?

```
poke player-choices index? next find player-choices "paper" 1 + select player-choices "paper"
```

Broken down:

```
>> ? poke
USAGE:
     POKE series index value

DESCRIPTION: 
     Replaces the series value at a given index, and returns the new value.
```

1. The series player-choices.
2. The index is position in player-choices of the value after "paper"
3. The value is whatever the current value is after paper added to 1

Find will return either the series where a value is found, or NONE.

```
>> find player-choices "paper"
== ["paper" 0 "scissors" 0]
```

But you want the index of next value hence:

```
>> index? next find player-choices "paper"
== 4
```

Select will return the next value of a series if it finds the value, which precedes it. Otherwise it will return none.

```
>> select pc "paper"
== 0
```

But we want to increase it by one, thus

```
>> 1 + select pc "paper"
== 1
```